# error in build to process builder in java

Tags: perl, java, javascript

I have devloped myself tagger and I want to host on the web. my server is based on jsp. But This tagger is based on svmtool and it has been written in Perl script. That's why, I have created one ".java" file. In this file I've created Processor builder and via the Runtime.getRuntime().exec through this process I am calling this file. It is working but it doesn't show my output. Plz help to solve this issue. For the better under standing below I am giving my java code and also given last line of output/stop the process: 
import java.io.*;

```
public class ExeCommand { String outS = "", errS="";
try {

    // run the Unix "type your  terminal command" command
        System.out.println ("Running tagger!");
String command = "perl /home/svmtool_v1.3.2/bin/SVMTagger.pl -V 4 -S LRL /home/svmtool_v1.3.2/models/ih/IN < /home/tomcat4.1.40/webapps/pos/textfile/tests.txt > /home/tomcat4.1.40/webapps/pos/textfile/output.txt"; Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

            // read the output from the command

            System.out.println("It will take time so keep the patience:\n" + command);
System.out.println ("First error line: " + stdError.readLine());

            // read any errors from the attempted command

            System.out.println("Please check your command (if any):\n");
            while ((errS = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Error:\t" + errS);
            }
stdError.close();


        System.out.println ("First output line: " + stdInput.readLine());
            while ((outS = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Output:\t" + outS);
            }
stdInput.close();

             System.out.println("Finished!");           
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("found exception: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            //System.exit(-1);  
        }
    System.out.println("Finished all!");
    }
}
```

After this nothing doing/ last output shows in terminal:
TAGGING < DIRECTION = left-to-right then right-to-left >

Comment: What do you mean by “It is working but it doesn't show my output”? Is it working or not? Anyway your question is off-topic here, this site is for usage and administration, not for programming. You can ask programming questions on [so].

Comment: Yes. It is working but it doesn't show my output.

Answer (score 0):

First, your perl script redirects its standard output to a file (
/home/tomcat4.1.40/webapps/pos/textfile/output.txt). So there is no way, you can capture standard output in Java.

Instead, you can use [tee](http://linux.101hacks.com/unix/tee-command-examples/) command which can write the output to both your output file and the standard output. Now, this can be captured in Java.

Second, use [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) instead of Runtime. Process Builder is more flexible and gives you options to capture the standard output / input / error.

```
ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder();
p.inheritIO(); // Sets the source and destination for subprocess standard I/O to be the same as those of the current Java process.
p.command("perl", "somescript.pl");
p.start();
```

Comment: First of thanks for reply, jagadish. I have tried but in error no changes. And one things, I want to add output is never generated.

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/627443/367165):

Sorry for the harsh words, but your code is a disaster. No compiler do something with it.

*I have made **no further tweaks** to your code*, I have the code modified so that it works at least:

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ExeCommand {

    /**
     * 
     * run the Unix "type your terminal command" command
     * 
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Running tagger!");

        String command = "perl /home/svmtool_v1.3.2/bin/SVMTagger.pl -V 4 -S LRL /home/svmtool_v1.3.2/models/ih/IN < /home/tomcat4.1.40/webapps/pos/textfile/tests.txt > /home/tomcat4.1.40/webapps/pos/textfile/output.txt";
//      String command = "ls -og";

        Process p = null;

        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // read the output from the command
        System.out.println("It will take time so keep the patience:\n" + command);
        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
        try {
            System.out.println(": " + stdError.readLine());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // read any errors from the attempted command
        System.out.println("Please check your command (if any):\n");
        try {
            String errS = "";
            while ((errS = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Error:\t" + errS);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            stdError.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        try {
            System.out.println("First output line: " + stdInput.readLine());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            String outS = "";
            while ((outS = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Output:\t" + outS);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            stdInput.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Finished!");
    }
}
```

Replace the lines 19 and 20

```
        String command = "perl /home/svmtool_v1.3.2/bin/SVMTagger.pl -V 4 -S LRL /home/svmtool_v1.3.2/models/ih/IN < /home/tomcat4.1.40/webapps/pos/textfile/tests.txt > /home/tomcat4.1.40/webapps/pos/textfile/output.txt";
//      String command = "ls -og";
```

with

```
//      String command = "perl /home/svmtool_v1.3.2/bin/SVMTagger.pl -V 4 -S LRL /home/svmtool_v1.3.2/models/ih/IN < /home/tomcat4.1.40/webapps/pos/textfile/tests.txt > /home/tomcat4.1.40/webapps/pos/textfile/output.txt";
        String command = "ls -og";
```

Then you get this output:

```
Running tagger!
It will take time so keep the patience:
ls -og
: null
Please check your command (if any):

First output line: insgesamt 12
Output: drwxrwxr-x 3 4096 Mai 23 20:51 bin
Output: drwxrwxr-x 3 4096 Apr 26 15:49 src
Output: -rw-rw-r-- 1   28 Apr 26 15:51 test
Finished!
```